# Knockout.js data-bind doesn't work when adding an Iframe

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am working on an web application. I use Knockout.js on the client side.

Everything is okay until I add an `iframe`. The `data-bind` of the `iframe` is okay but the outer's stops working. And I cannot click a button or do anything on the outer page.

This is my home page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  username:
  <input data-bind="value: name" />
  <br /> age:
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: age" />
  <button data-bind="click: increase">Increase</button>
  <br />
  <button onclick="show()">show</button>
  <script>
    var show = function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML + '<div><iframe src="iframe.html" width="300" height="300"></iframe></div>';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is its model:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function Outer(){
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable("thomas");
    self.age = ko.observable(15);

    self.increase = function(){
      self.age(self.age() + 1);
    }
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new Outer());
});
```

Right there I can click the <kbd>Increase</kbd> button to increase the `age` value. But when I click <kbd>show</kbd> to show the `iframe`, the data of the outer page disappears.

This is the `iframe` and its model:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function Inner(){
    var self = this;
    self.message = ko.observable("");
    self.text = ko.observable("begin");

    self.postData = function () {
      if (self.message().trim() !== '') {
        self.text(self.text() + "\n" + self.message())
      }
      self.message('');
    }
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new Inner());
});
```

[This is my example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qqw0d4X6Can13SjOoGth)

Comment: Did you try inspecting your code and stepping through it using the JS developer tools in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your `show` function is replacing all of the html in your page with a new copy. These copies aren't bound by Knockout anymore. You should instead add the `<iframe>` another way. For example, you can use Knockout!

```
<button data-bind="click: function() {showing(true)}">show</button>
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'iframe', if: showing}"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="iframe">
    <iframe src="iframe.html" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
</script>
```